# Can carbon fibre be injection molded?

Tags: carbon-fiber

I found very little information about that, but it says that its technically possible, but then why it isnt used instead regular carbon fibre machining? It sounds way easier...

Comment: Labor cost and time possibly...

Comment: Yes but you lose the lightness of the structure

Answer (score 2):

You can injection mold fiber-filled plastics, but the fibers have to be cut very short, which means that the part will not be as strong as it would be if the fibers were long and woven into cloth for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between fabric with long continuous fibers with a known orientation wetted with epoxy versus short, chopped up, randomly oriented fibers mixed into plastic.

The first cannot be injection molded because you cannot inject fabric.

Instead of fabric, you *might* be able to inject strands of continuous fiber rather than fabric but orientation is going to be pretty bad with very limited versatility in geometry (perhaps this is what your article was referring to?)

The second can be but is much weaker since the fibers are short and randomly oriented (some methods such as that used by APC Propellers use long pellets and can keep more fibers oriented the correct way, but still much weaker than long continuous fibers).

This is not really called injection molding carbon fiber. It is called injection molding fiber filled plastics. So depending on what you have in mind, your method doesn't exist or you are using the wrong search term